# From old Perforce service , how to check random files using command prompt

Tags: perforce

Have a old depot in Perforce, without knowing the filename wanted to get output of random files displayed in the command prompt. I used P4 files but it required particular file name to be accessed. Can we look into the depot files in random without knowing the file name specifically.

Comment: `p4 files`: [Provide information about files in the depot without accessing their contents.](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_files.html)

Answer (score 1):

There’s certainly no p4 “pick a random file from the depot” command. You can use `p4 files` to list files in the depot, such as with `p4 files //depot/...` to list all files in the depot, then select whichever filename you want.

Comment: this command results with no files found.

C:\Windows\system32>p4 -p  <port> files //...depot//... 

- no such file(s).

Comment: That’s not the right syntax. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an arbitrary (not random) file as quickly as possible, use `p4 files -m1 //...`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 files -m1 //...
//Modem_Tools/bin/biscuits.png#1 - add change 319 (binary)
```

This will fetch the (lexicographically) first file in the depot namespace and then return immediately.

If you want the actual file content, use `p4 print` instead of `p4 files`.

If you want a completely *random* file, you'll want to fetch a list of *all* the files (using `p4 files //...` without the `-m`) and then do a random selection on the client side (and then possibly pass the resulting file path[s] to another command like `p4 print` etc).

Comment: Do… do modems really need biscuits?

Comment: Oh, I get it. V.42bis(cuit)